# Magento 2 - Two dependencies in one field form?

Tags: magento2, forms, magento-2.0.4, dependency

**It is possible to add 2 depedencies to 1 field?**

Like this?

```
->addFieldMap($field_to_evaluate->getHtmlId(), $field_to_evaluate->getName())
->addFieldMap($field_to_show->getHtmlId(), $field_to_show->getName())
->addFieldDependence
 (
   $field_to_show->getName(),
   $field_to_evaluate->getName(),
   'dependecy 1'
  )
->addFieldDependence
  (
    $field_to_show->getName(),
    $field_to_evaluate->getName(),
   'dependecy 2'
  )
```

With this code it looks like only add the first dependency

**Can i also indicate if the $field_to_show hides insteand of show?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit

This seem to be an issue in Magento2, one possible workaround is

In your construct inject FieldFactory and also create a protected var for _fieldFactory

```
public function __construct(
    ......
    \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Dependency\FieldFactory $fieldFactory,
    ......
) {
    ....
    $this->_fieldFactory = $fieldFactory;
    ....
}
```

Then update your existing code to

```
$refField = $this->_fieldFactory->create(
     ['fieldData' => ['value' => 'dependecy 1,dependecy 2', 'separator' => ','], 'fieldPrefix' => '']
);


->addFieldDependence
 (
   $field_to_show->getName(),
   $field_to_evaluate->getName(),
   $refField
  )
```

I created an issue for this at https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4796

Try

```
->addFieldMap($field_to_evaluate->getHtmlId(), $field_to_evaluate->getName())
->addFieldMap($field_to_show->getHtmlId(), $field_to_show->getName())
->addFieldDependence
 (
   $field_to_show->getName(),
   $field_to_evaluate->getName(),
   array('dependecy 1','dependecy 2')
  )
```

To hide the field by default, you should set the default selected value of that option to the option that would trigger it to hide (to prevent any UI confusion)

Comment: I tried that, did not work get error `Notice: Array to string conversion` taking a look at `\vendor\magento\module-backend\Block\Widget\Form\Element\Dependence.php` the first dependency gets overwritten by the seconed if a separe it `$this->_depends[$fieldName][$fieldNameFrom] = $refField;`

Comment: Wow ty for your interest, have not tried it yet but it seems it may work

Answer (score -1):

```
$refField = $this->_fieldFactory->create(['fieldData' => ['value' => '1,2', 'separator' => ','], 'fieldPrefix' => '']
        );

       $this->setChild('form_after', $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
        'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Element\Dependence')
            ->addFieldMap($action->getHtmlId(), $action->getName())
            ->addFieldMap($anotherFieldweb->getHtmlId(), $anotherFieldweb->getName())
            ->addFieldMap($anotherFieldstore->getHtmlId(), $anotherFieldstore->getName())
            ->addFieldMap($anotherFieldhideorders->getHtmlId(), $anotherFieldhideorders->getName())
            ->addFieldMap($anotherFieldhideinvoice->getHtmlId(), $anotherFieldhideinvoice->getName())
            ->addFieldMap($anotherFieldhideshipment->getHtmlId(), $anotherFieldhideshipment->getName())
            ->addFieldMap($anotherFieldhidecredit->getHtmlId(), $anotherFieldhidecredit->getName())

            ->addFieldDependence($anotherFieldweb->getName(),$action->getName(),1)
            ->addFieldDependence($anotherFieldstore->getName(),$action->getName(),2)
            ->addFieldDependence($anotherFieldhideorders->getName(),$action->getName(),$refField)
            ->addFieldDependence($anotherFieldhideinvoice->getName(),$action->getName(),$refField)
            ->addFieldDependence($anotherFieldhideshipment->getName(),$action->getName(),$refField)
            ->addFieldDependence($anotherFieldhidecredit->getName(),$action->getName(),$refField)
        );
```

Comment: This is perfect solution